# bash scripting: how to find the absolute path of "symlink/.."?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, filepath

Given two files:

```
generic/scripts/hello.sh
parent/scripts -> generic/scripts
```

Upon calling `parent/scripts/hello.sh` from any location, I would like (in the script) to find the full path of the parent directory. In this case `parent`.

The main issue is that `parent/scripts/..` refers to `generic` in unix. On the other hand, everything involving regexes is not generic and may be error prone.

Solutions that don't work:

```
`dirname $0`/..
realpath  `dirname $0`/..
readlink -f `dirname $0`/..
`cd *something*/..; pwd`
`perl ... abs_path(...)`
```

All these will point to `generic` and not `parent` because of the symbolic link.

Everything involving regular expressions are not adaptable/generic, may fail for more complexes paths. There might be other `..` and symlinks in the path, you want the grand-parent, it's a directory name involving `..`, you call it via $PATH...

Moreover, I would like it to work in any case, even when it is called via `$PATH`.

Any simple safe solution for this simple problem? I mean it's just getting the parent directory after all!

***What I used:***

```
dir=$( dirname $( cd `dirname $0` >/dev/null; pwd ) )
```

Dunno if it is perfect but it seems to behave as expected.

Comment: how are you calling these scripts?

Comment: ideally, no restrictions should be put on how they can be called.

Comment: Your first solution works as long as you are actually using the `parent/scripts/hello.sh` to call the script.

Comment: "...it's just getting the parent directory after all" `generic` is hello's parent directory, that's why all the tools you use give you that.  If `parent/scripts` is not visible in `$0`, you'll not get it. On linux, `cd` to parent/scripts and do `ls -l /proc/$$` to see what the OS knows about where you are.

Comment: ...well ...somehow you have the information. It's either in $0 (when calling it from "outside" or $PATH), or to be combined with `pwd` if you are calling it within one of the subdirectories using a relative path. I just have the feeling that you have to manually handle several different cases and that you have to resolve the path using regular expressions ...which I personally think is fairly ugly ...just to get the parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
basename $(dirname $(dirname $0))
```

or perhaps just

```
$(dirname $(dirname $0))
```

It is unclear if you want `parent` alone or its full path.

Comment: double dirname does the trick ...the only to add is concatenating it with `pwd` when $0 is a relative path to also take into account the case when we are in one of the sub directories.

Comment: double dirname does not do the trick: dirname $(dirname ../../../) results in '..'.

Comment: @tstone2077 `$0` is quite unlikely to be equal to `../../../`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend 
1) use `pwd -P` which will always give you the *physical* path, and then *navigate with relative path to the other palce* This is most safe.

2) use `pwd -L`

Answer (score 1):

```
pushd $(dirname $0)
FOO=$(pwd)
popd
```

That gives you the absolute path of the directory that the script is running in.

Answer (score 0):

I call my scipt with this: `../script1` and it has a relative call to `../relative/script2`

```
`(cd $0/.. && pwd)`/relative/script2
```

is in script1

Answer (score 0):

in bash you could do some [string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) on `$PWD` if that variable is available.

For pathname of parent directory, use:

```
${PWD%/*}
```

Other examples :

```
me@host:/tmp/bash_string/ma ni-pu_la/tion$ echo -e \
"\$PWD or \${PWD} : " $PWD \
"\n\${PWD##/*}     : " ${PWD##/*} \
"\n\${PWD##*/}     : " ${PWD##*/} \
"\n\${PWD#/*}      : " ${PWD#/*} \
"\n\${PWD#*/}      : " ${PWD#*/} \
"\n\${PWD%%/*}     : " ${PWD%%/*} \
"\n\${PWD%%*/}     : " ${PWD%%*/} \
"\n\${PWD%/*}      : " ${PWD%/*} \
"\n\${PWD%*/}      : " ${PWD%*/} \
"\n" # Gives :
$PWD or ${PWD} :  /tmp/bash_string/ma ni-pu_la/tion 
${PWD##/*}     :  
${PWD##*/}     :  tion 
${PWD#/*}      :  tmp/bash_string/ma ni-pu_la/tion 
${PWD#*/}      :  tmp/bash_string/ma ni-pu_la/tion 
${PWD%%/*}     :  
${PWD%%*/}     :  /tmp/bash_string/ma ni-pu_la/tion 
${PWD%/*}      :  /tmp/bash_string/ma ni-pu_la 
${PWD%*/}      :  /tmp/bash_string/ma ni-pu_la/tion
```

Answer (score -3):

What about this:

```
echo `cd .. && pwd`
```